# Is it possible to us MSAccess to insert data through an external linked View in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, sql-server-2012, ms-access-2016

I'm using MS Access 2016 and SQL Server 2012.

I have single table with a schemabound view over the table. Our design was to allow our users to insert data through the view so we can do some id lookups for them and audit who inserted the record using an instead of insert trigger.

No matter how I configure it, Access doesn't want to let me add records to the view. If I use the table, it works as expected and it lets me insert new records.

I've tried the following:

- Opening the external table and try to add new record at bottom - no luck
- Creating an "Update" query - no luck
- Creating an "Append" query - no luck
- Creating a form, setting the view as a source, and setting Data Entry = Yes - no luck

Is what I'm trying to do even possible? I come from a SQL/C# background, and have only basic MSAccess skills. Any help is appreciated!

EDIT: I found out the View had a group by when it shouldn't have. I corrected that, but now it is complaining that it is not updatable because there are multiple underlying tables.

EDIT2: I've made progress but it's not ideal.

More info:

- This view represents a datawarehouse fact, and joins to two dimension tables to get business keys.
- I was able to get this to work by creating a "dummy" table with all the same fields, then creating a view over that. I was able to insert, but the data comes back "deleted" immediately because my instead of trigger fires.
- Data went to the right place, but obviously the view doesn't show any data since it's not actually querying the correct tables anymore.
- Clearly the view is irrelevant now, and I'll likely write the trigger over the dummy table.
- It's not ideal, but I think my solution will be to have them insert through this dummy table, and then have a second view that does the joins so they can view the results.

I appreciate the detailed answer that was given, but unfortunately it didn't help this situation.

Comment: While similar, I don't believe this is a duplicate of the linked question, to anyone looking to categorize this later or voting to close it.

Answer (score 1):

If the view is up-datable from SSMS, then it will be so in Access. So, before you try anything in Access, you have to first ensure that the view is up-datable in SSMS.  So not all SQL views are up-datable.

You would do beyond well to test/check this in SSMS.

Once you done this, then you have to link the table from access. (and if you messed around with modify to the view, then delete the linked view in access and re-link). YOU MUST delete the access link and re-link.

And the linking process needs extra CARE. WHEN you link, you will be asked for a primary key for the view. Because a view can have multiple PK's (as a result of several tables), then Access can't know or guess. And far worse is that a SQL view does not in fact have a defined PK, and there is no command or means that Access can use to determine this. So you are PROMPTED during that link process. I note this issue, since if you are using some VBA re-link code, then if you re-link and change the database (or server), then during that re-link process, the PK setting you had will be lost. You ONLY get this prompt during a link of a new table - not a re-link. So, keep this important detail in mind.

You can after the fact (after linking a table) execute the following command to re-enable or "set" which column is to be the PK with this command in Access:

I in fact use this routine:

```
Sub createPK(strTable As String, strPK As String)

  CurrentDb.Execute "CREATE UNIQUE INDEX " & strPK & _
   " ON " & strTable & " (" & strPK & ")  WITH PRIMARY"

End Sub
```

So, to set a PK for a linked view, then I use this:

```
 Call createPK("dbo_tblHotels","ID")
```

As a FYI:
The above command DOES NOT create a index in access for that linked view, but is a MEANS to ONLY TELL Access what column to use for the PK. So, in this context, the create index command is not creating a index, but is the means/approach/how/process in which you can tell/set in Access what column is to be used for the PK view. As noted, you only need to do the above if you using code to re-link (or create) a table (view in this case).

So, if you using the Access UI, and you link to a view? Then Access will prompt/ask you to choose a column for the PK. You can as noted after linking use the above routine/command in Access to set which column is to be used as the PK if you missed the prompt, or as noted are using some VBA code to re-link.

A re-link (refresh) with the Access UI to the SAME database will preserve the PK setting. But if you change the connection string (database or server name), then the PK setting will be lost.

Answer (score 0):

First, [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/212662/insert-into-multi-table-view-in-sql-server) is a really good answer to a similar question.  Try adding an INSTEAD OF trigger to the view in SQL Server.  In order to insert into a view the key columns must all be present and each table must be UNION'ed together.  INSTEAD OF trigger can be made to do exactly as you wish.

Comment: Thanks, but this wasn't relevant. I don't have a partitioned view, and a union all was not applicable.

Comment: Did you get what you were looking for?  I see your note above.